# User settings are back to fresh installation

Tags: users, user-profile, accounts

I was trying to set Plex and found this instructions to allow Plex user to access certain folders https://www.linuxcapable.com/install-plex-media-server-on-ubuntu-linux/#Configure-Media-Files-Folders-Permissions-with-Plex-Media-Server-on-Ubuntu

So I wrote:

```
sudo chown -R plex:plex /home/
```

But the process was taking to long and I kill it. And after I wrote:

```
sudo chown -R plex:plex /home/myuserfolder/Videos
```

And when I restarted my user is like I've just installed Ubuntu 23.04 √°°✓

I've lost all my settings? Anything I can do? How I can backup the next time to prevent something like this? (or maybe to migrate account to a new installation...)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have any other users for this computer? Usually different user files are owned by respective users. Your first command made all the files for all the users including you, owned by an user called "plex". As a result you don't own your configuration files (settings) any more. Since plex owns all the files, you don't have access to them. Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't have other users. My user is working, but the settings are back to default (desktop wallpaper, theme, start programs... Everything). So you are saying that my settings can be somewhere? Where I can look? Thank you!

Comment: Your setting are in the folder `/home/myuserfolder/` in various hidden files and folders. These files and folders have names starting with a "dot" `.`. You can un-hide then in the Files app by pressing Ctrl+H. Remember, you will have to change the ownership  of all the files and folders that are inside the hidden folders.

Comment: Ok. So I should do it through a command in the terminal, because I see I don't have now ownership of most of the user files and folders. Great job by me. If you can tell me how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Something like `sudo chown groupname:username /home/`?

Comment: The solution was `sudo chown -R groupname:username /home/`. You need the -R to do it recoursive and change all the folders and files.

Comment: I am glad you found a solution. Please click the **Answer Your Own Question** button below and provide an answer. Then accept your answer by clicking on the gray check mark next to it and turn it green. This will help others.

Answer (score 0):

With `sudo chown -R plex:plex /home/` I change the ownership of all the files and folders in /home/ to plex user. I interrupted the process, so only some where affected.

To undo it I just wrote `sudo chown -R groupname:username /home/`

Thank you to @user68186!!

ifrit